# How to cumulative sum in power BI without taking value of the month itself

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

How to cumulative sum in powerbi
i use this dax

```
Total Orders Before = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( supermarket_sales[Total Orders] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( supermarket_sales ),
        supermarket_sales[Date] <= MAX (supermarket_sales[Date])
    )
)
```

[then i have this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55oRc.png)
I don't want it to sum the value of the current month.

Can you advice me how to write measure DAX formula please.

Thank you very much
[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbo3M.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using calculated column in DAX

```
Total Orders Before = 
Var Thismonth = supermarket_sales[Month]
Return CALCULATE (SUM (supermarket_sales[Orders]), FILTER (ALL(supermarket_sales ), supermarket_sales[Month] <= Thismonth-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you do it in measure please?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by measure also

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM(supermarket_sales[Orders]), FILTER(ALL(supermarket_sales), supermarket_sales[Month] <= SELECTEDVALUE(supermarket_sales[Month])-1))
```

[image]

Select Orders field and select `'Show items with no data'`

Comment: If it solved your issue, accept answer and upvote